# Cloudinary give max size error for upload using android

Tags: java, cloudinary

**Exception**:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: File size too large. Got 25365853. Maximum is 10485760.
```

But the actual size is 1873795 bytes.

Any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please contact Cloudinary via a [Support ticket](http://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) and share some more information about this issue. Please attach the file itself, and share the timestamp of the upload. Then, the team will be able to have a deeper look at it and assist.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. Thanks to Cloudinary support team, I was converting it to png, which is scaling it to 10+mb from ~2mb.